# Filter the_content() in the Quote Post Format to Display Quotes

Tags: the-content, post-formats

I'm customizing a theme for a client and I want to leverage post formats.

On the quote post format I would like

```
the_content();
```

to be wrapped in a two spans that contains quotation marks that I could style and position.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = '<span>"</span>'.$content.'<span>"</span>';

echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

**CSS Solution:**

```
<blockquote>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</blockquote>

blockquote:before{
   content: '"';
}

blockquote:after{
   content: '"';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @sisir but a slightly different take on a few of the specifics. For functions.php:

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'add_quotes_to_quote' );
function add_quotes_to_quote( $content ) {
    if( get_post_format() == "quote" ) {
        return '<span class="openquote">"</span>' . $content . '<span class="closequote">"</span>';
    }
}
```

If you're using `post_class()` and don't need [perfect browser support](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/), you can use CSS something like this (.entry-content being some wrapping element around your body content):

```
.format-quote .entry-content:before,.format-quote .entry-content:after {
    display:inline-block;
    content:'"';
    /* your styles */
}
```